# why is sorting of array not working in reactjs even though it comes already sorted from backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have an array that looks similar to this

```
const chapters= [
   { index:1, title:'chapter-1', lessons:[] }
   { index:2, title:'chapter-2', lessons:[] }
   { index:3, title:'chapter-3', lessons:[] }
]
```

And this comes already sorted from backend on the basis of index

Now  I want to create a state of chapters array in react by this approach

```
chapters.forEach(chapter=>{
   this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              chapters: [
                ...prevState.chapters,
                {
                  chapterTitle: chapter.title,
                  chapterIndex: chapter.index,
                  lessons,
                },
              ],
            };
          });
});
```

the problem is the state is not sorted. I even tried to sort the states after they have been written once. For that I follwed this code i found in stackoverflow

```
const sortedChapters= this.state.chapters.sort((a, b) =>
            a.index > b.index ? 1 : b.index > a.index ? -1 : 0
          );
this.setState({ chapters: sortedChapters});
```

But no luck. please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't explain why it isn't retaining the order from your API call, but [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) does mutate the original array. So your `setState` is probably not triggering a re-render. This could be part of your problem.

Comment: I tried  using for loop instead of foreach loop,and it works fine,can you explain why this happens?

Comment: And is there any way I can stick to forEach because it seems faster than for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should almost never set state in a forEach loop.
Try this:

```
const chaptersFromBackend = [
   { index:1, title:'chapter-1', lessons:[] }
   { index:2, title:'chapter-2', lessons:[] }
   { index:3, title:'chapter-3', lessons:[] }
];

const chaptersFormatted = chaptersFromBackend.map(chapter => {
   return {chapterTitle: chapter.title, chapterIndex: chapter.index, lessons: chapter.lessons};
});

this.setState({chapters: chaptersFormatted});
```

Because of the way react works, the last line wont mess with any other properties you have in your state. I.e. state.foo will be untouched.

Comment: This is a much better approach than calling multiple `setState`s